# are extensions bad for performance in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Swift offers the ability to write extensions. I do that a lot to make my code easier to read. Not sure if they are harmless. I am wondering, would it be better to just omit extensions, because of performance reasons?

Comment: 20 years ago I was on the team writing code for the then unreleased  Symbian OS. Some of the apps were dog slow and everybody was examining the code and architecture to speed it up. I still chuckle at the person who changed i++ to ++i in for loops as their solution. Yes ++i is more efficient than i++. Did it make a difference to the efficiency of their program compared to the bigger picture of where there might have been efficiency problems. Did it bugger. My advice: move on unless the documentation for extensions warn that there is a severe performance overhead in using them, does it?

Comment: @krompir You have a debugger. You have Instruments. What did they tell you about how extensions were messing up the performance of your app?

Comment: @MartinH "move on unless the documentation for extensions warn that there is a severe performance overhead in using them, does it" Okay, with Swift that's a rotten argument. Dictionaries are a performance hit. Arrays, esp. nested arrays, used to be a huge performance hit (not sure if they still are). Big apps (100,000 lines) are a performance hit. How do I know? Forums, blogs, SO - not "the documentation". Our benevolent overlords do _not_ in fact warn us of these things. So please let's not pretend that the documentation is the place to look for answers or advice on this.

Comment: @matt I don't disagree with what you say, but you are interpreting that statement verbatim literally when it was intended to be figurative ;-)

Comment: @MartinH "Move on unless the documentation for extensions warn" is figurative? How? It says what it says. And I'm saying that what it says is bad advice. I agree that worrying about whether extensions magically cause some kind of performance issue seems extremely silly, but not for the reason you give in _that_ sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple encourages the use of extensions. You can read more about them on the Swift documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about that. Compiler while compiling, treat these extensions as much as like a just another function call. Because `extension` is not a dynamic behavior but a static one. When you use `performSelector` it costs more performance than a normal instance method or extension as it is a dynamic behavior.