# Swift: private / fileprivate runtime performance

Tags: swift, performance

I'm aware of the fact that there shouldn't be runtime performance differences when moving methods of a class to extensions (as answered in [Swift extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895972/swift-extension) and [are extensions bad for performance in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894879/are-extensions-bad-for-performance-in-swift)).

But I can not find much documentation about if there is any difference in runtime performance by changing the necessary `private` properties to `fileprivate`, which is generally needed in order to allow the methods (moved to an extension in the same file as the class), to access them.

Is anyone aware of any performance difference? (I don't care about compile time differences, which I think do not exist in this case anyway, just runtime.)

Comment: Aren't you in danger of optimizing prematurely?

Comment: I agree with @matt. Besides, I would hope that *runtime* performance between the two matter little, as the binary created by the build is a single unit.

Comment: Possibly? Anyway I would like to know the answer, since it may be useful for "optimization time"... Thanks!

Comment: Also, I did not say in which stage of development I am. In this case I have a mature class and I'm improving readability of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would there be such a difference? These privacy terms are mostly just notes to the compiler to forbid certain kinds of access.

The important gains at runtime come from using Whole Module Optimization and/or declaring your classes `final`. This allows dynamic dispatch to be switched off.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Do you know if there could be a link to some Apple's doc about this kind runtime performance questions, or to someone else's measurements with Instruments or the like? I'm just curious...